# how to use runModelOnFrame in flutter Tflite?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

I have `classifyImage` method that predict Images that I have get from Camera.

I use this code and it worked but it detect all image wrong !!

am I doing something wrong?

```
var isAccident = [];
```

```
classifyImage(CameraImage Frame) async{
  isAccident = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
      bytesList: Frame.planes.map((e) => e.bytes).toList());
  setState(() {});
}
```

I have tried to run the model on images in the gallery and they are detected right using this code

```
classifyImage(File image) async {
  isAccident = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
    path: image.path,
  );
  setState(() {});
}
```